# Find the line through $P = (2,4,7) $ that intersects and is perpendicular to the line : $x = -1 + t, y = -2 + 3t, z = 4 $

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, vectors

> Find the line through $P = (2,4,7) $ that intersects and is
>   perpendicular to the line : $x = -1 + t, y = -2 + 3t, z = 4 $

I set up a system of equations and obtained :

$-1 + t = x_0 +2 \\ -2 + 3t = y_0 + 4 \\ 4 = z_0 + 7$

Solving for each and putting them I obtain the vector  $ v_1 = <t -3, 3t-6, -3>$ I then set the direction vector as  $ v_2 =<1,3,4>$

Since $v_1 \cdot v_2 = 0 $ means they are orthogonal I obtain :

$<t -3, 3t-6, -3> \cdot <1,3,4> = 0  $

Multiplying out and solving for t I get $t = 10/21$

Would I now just substitute my given value for t back into $t_1$ ?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you missing a $t$ in your equation $z=4$? If the given equation is correct, the direction vector for the line should be $\langle 1,3,0\rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done! You just need to find the right value for $t$.

Let $Q_t:=(-1 + t,-2 + 3t,4)$ then the vector $Q_t-P=(t−3,3t−6,−3)$ (that you have already found) should be **perpendicular** to the direction vector of the given line $Q_1-Q_0=(1,3,0)$. Find such $t$. Then the desired line is
$$s\to P+s\cdot (Q_t-P).$$

Comment: I am having trouble setting up the equation to find t, since (1,3,0) is the direction vector call it V would I dot that with the vector qt - p and solve for t assuming the result would have to be zero to make them orthogonal. Then go back and substitute the found value  for t ??

Comment: @DougRay Yes, that's right!!

Comment: @DougRay Are you still interested in finding this line?

Comment: Hey Robert I actually found the line I just have not had time to update this question with the full walkthrough and answer , thanks so much for your help :) !!!!

Answer (score 0):

**1.** The plane $P_1$ which includes the line
$$\ell_0: x = -1 + t, y = -2 + 3t, z = 4 $$
and the point $p=(2,4,7)$ is
$$\boxed{3x-y-z=-5}$$
**2.** The plane $P_2$ perpendicular to the line $\ell_0$ psses through point $p=(2,4,7)$ is
$$\boxed{x+3y=14}$$
**3.** Intersection of planes $P_1$ and $P_2$ is desired line that is
$$\boxed{\dfrac{x-14}{-3}=y=\dfrac{-z+47}{10}}$$